# How do I create/update quill blots in vue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, quill

I see the documentation for adding a quill blot, but as a new programmer learning js through the use of vue, I can't figure out where to put it. I want to change the class names to use tailwind css classes.

I have 'vue-quill-editor' installed through npm and have the editor working with the code below.

```
<template>
  <section class="container">
    <no-ssr>
      <div
        v-quill:myQuillEditor="editorOption"
        class="quill-editor"
        :content="content"
        @change="onEditorChange($event)"
      ></div>
    </no-ssr>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
/*
Emits the html content to parent using editor-content
a parent example <quill @editor-content="form.content = $event" />
*/
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      content: "<p>Start typing post...</p>",
      editorOption: {
        // some quill options
        modules: {
          toolbar: [
            ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
            ["blockquote", "code-block"],
            [{ list: "ordered" }, { list: "bullet" }],
            [{ indent: "-1" }, { indent: "+1" }], // outdent/indent

            [{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }], // custom dropdown
            [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],

            [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }], // dropdown with defaults from theme
            [{ font: [] }],
            [{ align: [] }],

            ["clean"]
          ]
        }
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onEditorChange({ editor, html, text }) {
      this.content = html;
      this.$emit("editor-content", this.content);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.quill-editor {
  min-height: 200px;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in mounted hooks, because quill operate on DOM.